# Posting to /PROFILE_ID/links only accepts link and message parameters

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink, posting

According to the documentation the links endpoint takes picture, name, and description as parameters.
From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ under the Publishing section

```
Method                  Description                         Arguments

/PROFILE_ID/links   Publish a link on the given profile     link, message, picture, name, caption, description
```

However when I try these parameters are ignored. Python example below.

```
res = requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/links", 
                    data = {'access_token':t.auth_payload,
                            'message':'testing',
                            'link':'http://percolate.com',
                            'picture':'http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/facebook_news_feed.png',
                            'caption':'this is a caption', 
                            'description':'this is a description', 
                            'name':'this is a name'})
```

Which results in:

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on this issue. The links endpoint becomes more and more useless while the /feed endpoint finally has the features I've needed. /feed used to lose the share action when posting a link. That has since been fixed.

If you have issues with the links endpoint. Switch to /feed and see if it suites your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation about creating a link for a user only states the following:

> You can post a link on the user's behalf by issuing an HTTP POST request to PROFILE_ID/feed with the publish_stream permissions and the following parameters.
>
> **Parameter**: link and message

The other fields are taken from the metadata of the page URL given in the 'link' param.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: Look under Publishing here 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Method                 Description                     Arguments
/PROFILE_ID/links Publish a link on the given profile link, message, picture, name, caption, description

Comment: Also I must use the /links endpoint because I need the share functionality and want the via as part of the data up top instead of down below.